# WPS very slowly when typing with ibus vietnamese

Tags: ibus, wps-office

I have installed WPS Office 11.1.0.10161 from official website with .deb package.
When I typing vietnamese by ibus-unikey iput method, it's very slowly to display what I typed. The problem occurred in WPS Writer and WPS Presentation, but every thing work fine in WPS Spreadsheet.
How can I fix it?
My system is ubuntu 20.04 and Kernel Version: 5.8.0-50-generic.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with you when I was using WPS downloaded at [official website](https://linux.wps.com) and trying to type Vietnamese with [ibus-bamboo](https://github.com/BambooEngine/ibus-bamboo). But since I changed to use [WPS snap package](https://snapcraft.io/wps-2019-snap) then its working very well with me: app starting faster, no more ibus-bamboo issues, maybe this can help you.